# Create a function called printtype that takes one parameter

Tags: python

If the parameter is a string, return "String"
If the parameter is an int, return "Int"
If the parameter is a float, return "Float"

Code:-

```
def printtype(x): 
    if isinstance(x,int):
        return x
    elif isinstance(x,float):
            return x
    else:
        isinstance(x,str)
        return x
print(type(printtype(5)))
print(type(printtype(5.0)))
print(type(printtype("5")))
```

Error:-
Float' != 2.5 : You must retrun Float if a dloat is passed into the printtype function

Comment: why aren't you returning the answer right away in printtype method?

Comment: Why are you returning `x`? That isn't what the problem asks you to return.

Comment: That's not a Python error; it looks like something returned by a grading framework that calls `printtype`. Probably something like `assert printtype(2.5) == "Float", f'Error:- 'Float' != 2.5: You must return Float if a float is passed into the printtype function.`

Comment: This appears to be a terrible assignment, by the way. You rarely ever want to perform this kind of run-time type check in real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could solve your issue.

```
def printtype(x): 
    if isinstance(x,int):
        return "Int"
    elif isinstance(x,float):
        return "Float"
    elif isinstance(x,str):
        return "String"
    else:
        return "Unknown type"
      
print(printtype(5))
print(printtype(5.0))
print(printtype("5"))
```

**Output::**

```
Int
Float
String
```